# How to describe a positional relationship between two objects with respect to a certain direction?

Tags: adverbs

[image]

I am trying to describe the positional relationship between the red circle and the green triangle **with reference to direction A** indicated by the blue arrow. I thought of two examples:

> 1. The red circle is located **above** the green triangle in direction A.
> 2. The red circle is located **downstream** of the green triangle in direction A.

Are there any problems with my examples?

Comment: How did you come up with "upstream"? Some similar usage? Off the top of my head it doesn't seem to fit.

Comment: I made a mistake and corrected it to "downstream".

Comment: I can't resolve directional movement with stationary objects, so I'm still not clear what you are asking. Perhaps "The red circle is *ahead of/in front of* the green triangle"?

Comment: Direction A is an undefined direction, so may be a vertical upward direction, a vertical downward direction, a north direction, a south direction, a southeast direction, or ...  I would like to know how to describe the positional relationship between two stationary objects  by using such a direction.  It seems that  "ahead of/ in front of" makes sense.

Comment: Upstream/downstream it's the same.  There's no absolute direction. Up can be up, but it needn't be.  That's why we have coordinate systems.

Answer (score 2):

Neither sentence you show is applicable.

> The red circle is located above and to the right of the green triangle.

Comment: I would like to use "direction A ".

Comment: There is no single word in English for "direction A", AFAIK. If it were a *map*, one could  say `northeast`, or on a protractor, `at 45 degrees` or `at 1/4 pi radians`, or as @Tᴚoɯɐuo suggests, use military 'clock' terminology.

Comment: I think "above" can be used with reference to "vertical directions".  I would like to define a certain direction and then explain a positional relationship between two objects with reference to the certain direction.

Comment: Yes, but the direction is not only above, but **to the right** -- not an orthogonal direction.

Answer (score 0):

In informal contexts you can use the analogue clock-face:

The triangle is at the circle's eight o'clock.

The circle is at the triangle's two o'clock.

Comment: I would like to use "direction A ".